# Get specific CSS Hover properties

Tags: css, hover

How can I see the differences in the style of an element with and without the hover property.

I want a full list of CSS styles that **only happen** when the specific element is hovered (or that has the :hover state).

Comment: Dev Tools (F12) > Select the element > In the styles tab 'Filter' :hov > Tick the box :hover

Comment: Which browser ?

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just look in the CSS file and find the `selector:hover` declaration?

Comment: Did just that actually, there are a lot of elements and different properties in the codebase, anyway, i could find it thankfully.